# How can I partially fill both positive and negative space in an SVG shape?

Tags: css, svg

I want fill SVG progress by two different colors

SVG code is

```html
<path d="M129.309 26.342C129.201 22.884 128.659 22.009 125.904
19.457C112.662 7.974 95.397 1 76.491 1C34.797 1 1 34.8 1 76.494C1 118.184 34.797
151.982 76.491 151.982C95.409 151.982 112.68 145.002 125.928 133.503C129.087 
130.575 129.316 129.86 129.334 124.839L129.335 79.82L85.241 116.82C76.966 123.516
64.149 123.245 56.409 114.268C48.67 105.293 50.122 92.101 58.808 84.822C58.889
84.753 68.674 76.542 68.741 76.485C68.675 76.43 58.889 68.222 58.808 68.15C50.122
60.872 48.669 47.677 56.409 38.7C64.149 29.729 76.966 29.457 85.241 36.15L129.335
73.153V26.342H129.309Z" stroke="#27348B" stroke-width="2" stroke-miterlimit="10"/>
```

[image]
like this TT

Answer (score 1):

Well first you need to separate out the inner shape as a new shape that you draw first - you can't fill a negative space in SVG. And then you need to construct two gradients that are  defined in terms of the drawing surface (userSpaceOnUse) rather than the default of % of the filled shape. Once you do that, you can control the % fill by making the middle stops of the gradient the same in both fills.

```html
<svg width="200px" height="200px" viewBox="0 0 200 200">
  <defs>
    <linearGradient id="inner" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="0" y1="0" x2="205" y2="0">
      <stop offset="0%"  stop-color="white" />
      <stop offset="0%"  stop-color="red" />
      <stop offset="40%"  stop-color="red" />
      <stop offset="40%" stop-color="white" />
      <stop offset="100%" stop-color="white" />
    </linearGradient>
    
     <linearGradient id="outer" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="0" y1="0" x2="205" y2="0">
      <stop offset="0%"  stop-color="white" />
      <stop offset="0%"  stop-color="#22D" />
      <stop offset="40%"  stop-color="#22D" />
      <stop offset="40%" stop-color="white" />
      <stop offset="100%" stop-color="white" />
    </linearGradient>
  </defs>
  
<path d="
M130.309 73.342 
L130.335 79.82
h -1          
L85.241 116.82
C76.966 123.516 64.149 123.245 56.409 114.268 
         
C48.67 105.293 50.122 92.101 58.808 84.822
C58.889 84.753 68.674 76.542 68.741 76.485
C68.675 76.43 58.889 68.222 58.808 68.15 
C50.122 60.872 48.669 47.677 56.409 38.7
C64.149 29.729 76.966 29.457 85.241 36.15 
L129.335 73.153" 
stroke="none" stroke-width="2" stroke-miterlimit="10" fill="url(#inner)" />  
  
  
<path d="M129.309 26.342C129.201 22.884 128.659 22.009 125.904 19.457C112.662 7.974 95.397 1 76.491 1C34.797 1 1 34.8 1 76.494C1 118.184 34.797 151.982 76.491 151.982C95.409 151.982 112.68 145.002 125.928 133.503C129.087 130.575 129.316 129.86 129.334 124.839L129.335 79.82L85.241 116.82C76.966 123.516 64.149 123.245 56.409 114.268C48.67 105.293 50.122 92.101 58.808 84.822C58.889 84.753 68.674 76.542 68.741 76.485C68.675 76.43 58.889 68.222 58.808 68.15C50.122 60.872 48.669 47.677 56.409 38.7C64.149 29.729 76.966 29.457 85.241 36.15L129.335 73.153V26.342H129.309Z" stroke="#27348B" stroke-width="2" stroke-miterlimit="10" fill="url(#outer)"/>

</svg>
```

```html
<svg width="200px" height="200px" viewBox="0 0 200 200">
  <defs>
    <linearGradient id="inner" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="0" y1="0" x2="205" y2="0">
      <stop offset="0%"  stop-color="white" />
      <stop offset="0%"  stop-color="red" />
      <stop offset="55%"  stop-color="red" />
      <stop offset="55%" stop-color="white" />
      <stop offset="100%" stop-color="white" />
    </linearGradient>
    
     <linearGradient id="outer" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="0" y1="0" x2="205" y2="0">
      <stop offset="0%"  stop-color="white" />
      <stop offset="0%"  stop-color="#22D" />
      <stop offset="55%"  stop-color="#22D" />
      <stop offset="55%" stop-color="white" />
      <stop offset="100%" stop-color="white" />
    </linearGradient>
  </defs>
  
<path d="
M130.309 73.342 
L130.335 79.82
h -1          
L85.241 116.82
C76.966 123.516 64.149 123.245 56.409 114.268 
         
C48.67 105.293 50.122 92.101 58.808 84.822
C58.889 84.753 68.674 76.542 68.741 76.485
C68.675 76.43 58.889 68.222 58.808 68.15 
C50.122 60.872 48.669 47.677 56.409 38.7
C64.149 29.729 76.966 29.457 85.241 36.15 
L129.335 73.153" 
stroke="none" stroke-width="2" stroke-miterlimit="10" fill="url(#inner)" />  
  
  
<path d="M129.309 26.342C129.201 22.884 128.659 22.009 125.904 19.457C112.662 7.974 95.397 1 76.491 1C34.797 1 1 34.8 1 76.494C1 118.184 34.797 151.982 76.491 151.982C95.409 151.982 112.68 145.002 125.928 133.503C129.087 130.575 129.316 129.86 129.334 124.839L129.335 79.82L85.241 116.82C76.966 123.516 64.149 123.245 56.409 114.268C48.67 105.293 50.122 92.101 58.808 84.822C58.889 84.753 68.674 76.542 68.741 76.485C68.675 76.43 58.889 68.222 58.808 68.15C50.122 60.872 48.669 47.677 56.409 38.7C64.149 29.729 76.966 29.457 85.241 36.15L129.335 73.153V26.342H129.309Z" stroke="#27348B" stroke-width="2" stroke-miterlimit="10" fill="url(#outer)"/>

</svg>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm separating the base (#b9) and the heart (#h) in 2 paths.
I'm reusing the base and I'm clipping tue use element with the heart.
I'm filling both the base and the use element with the same gradient.
Also the Use element has a filter that is changing the blue to red.

```css
svg{border:solid; width:200px}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 135 152">
<defs>  
<filter id="b2r">
    <feColorMatrix in="SourceGraphic" type="matrix" values="0 0 1 0 0
       0 1 0 0 0
       1 0 0 0 0
       0 0 0 1 0"></feColorMatrix>
  </filter>
  
<linearGradient id="lg">
   <stop offset="0" stop-color="blue"></stop>
   <stop offset="0" stop-color="blue">
     <animate 
       attributeName="offset"
       attributeType="XML"
       from="0" to="1"
       dur="5s"
       repeatCount="indefinite"/>
   </stop>
  <stop offset="0" stop-color="transparent"></stop>
   <stop offset="1" stop-color="transparent"></stop>
  </linearGradient> 
<clipPath   id="cp">
  <path id="h" d="M129.334 124.839L129.335 79.82L85.241 116.82C76.966 123.516 64.149 123.245 56.409 114.268C48.67 105.293 50.122 92.101 58.808 84.822C58.889 84.753 68.674 76.542 68.741 76.485C68.675 76.43 58.889 68.222 58.808 68.15C50.122 60.872 48.669 47.677 56.409 38.7C64.149 29.729 76.966 29.457 85.241 36.15L129.335 73.153V26.342H129.309Z"  />
 />
  </clipPath>
  </defs>
<g fill="url(#lg)">  
<path id="b" d="M129.309 26.342C129.201 22.884 128.659 22.009 125.904 19.457C112.662 7.974 95.397 1 76.491 1C34.797 1 1 34.8 1 76.494C1 118.184 34.797 151.982 76.491 151.982C95.409 151.982 112.68 145.002 125.928 133.503C129.087 130.575 129.316 129.86 129.334 124.839z" stroke="blue" stroke-width="2" stroke-miterlimit="10" /> 
  
<use xlink:href="#b" filter="url(#b2r)" clip-path="url(#cp)" />  
</svg>
```